# Laravel Eloquent - Attach vs Sync

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, eloquent, relationship

What is the difference between `attach()` and `sync()` in Laravel 4's Eloquent ORM? I've tried to look around but couldn't find anything!

Answer (score 178, accepted):

**attach():**

- Insert related models when working with many-to-many relations
- No array parameter is expected

Example:

```
$user = User::find(1);
$user->roles()->attach(1);
```

**sync():**

Similar to the `attach()` method, the `sync()` method is used to attach related models. However, the main differences are:

- `sync()` accepts an array of IDs to place on the pivot table
- Secondly, **most important**, the sync method will delete the data from the pivot table if the model does not exist in the array, and insert only the new items to the pivot table.

Example:

**user_role**

```
id  user_id role_id
1    12       1
2    12       5
3    12       2
```

```
$user = User::find(12);
$user->roles()->sync(array(1, 2, 3));
```

The above operation will delete:

```
id  user_id role_id
2    12       5
```

And insert `role_id 3` to the table.

**user_role table**

```
id  user_id role_id
1    12       1
3    12       2
4    12       3
```

Comment: Thank you! So in theory, using `$user()->roles()->detach($oldIDs)` followed by `$user()->roles()->attach($newIDs)` is the same as `$user()->roles()->sync($newIDs)`, right?

Comment: Also there is one second argument for sync() that is by default true, if you pass false, then the non matching will not be deleted. Refer: http://laravel.com/api/4.2/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Relations/MorphToMany.html#method_sync

Comment: get last insert id in sync?

Comment: @Deena actually pivot tables don't need any ID - so you don't get any ID back :) but you can get the related ones by reusing the model object variable

Comment: How about when pivot table does not only have 2 columns(user_id, role_id). I want add 1 column is value to pivot table, how can I add data to that column

Comment: I'm not sure when it was introduced, but there now exists a `syncWithoutDetaching()` method - is the only difference between `attach()` and `syncWithoutDetaching()` that the latter can accept an array of IDs?

Comment: @CGriffin I find it interesting that `attach/detach` methods have also `$touch` parameter (not really documented well, but may update timestamps?) - both `sync` and `attach`  touch based on `protected $touches = [];`, but in case of `attach` you can manually turn it off  ...For basic operations there should be no difference though....

Comment: Small Note: The attach() method accept arrays of IDs  or single value as input. The same goes for the detach() method.

Comment: A subtle-but-critical difference between `attach()` and any `sync…()` method is that `attach()` **always adds a record**, even if the models are already related. If the pivot table did not have its own record IDs, managing one relationship across multiple records could grow complicated.

Answer (score 63):

*To make it even simpler:*

The `attach` function only adds records to the Pivot table.

The `sync` function replaces the current records with the new records. This is very useful for updating a model.

**Example:**

Assuming you have a created Post that has many Tags attached on it where the Tags ID's are **[1,2,3]**.

And the user has the ability to update the Post and its Tags.

The user will send you the new Tags ID's [3,4,5].

If you use the `sync` function, the new Tags of the Post will be **[3,4,5]** only.

If you use the `attach` function, the new Tags of the Post will be **[1,2,3,4,5]**.

Comment: my problem is similar to this . i can use your answer to solve it thanks. https://stackoverflow.com/a/36573783/308578

Answer (score 9):

Posted answers don't mention `syncWithoutDetaching`, so here is my simple take.

If you want to:

- add the model to the relation, **allowing for duplicates**, use `attach()`
- add the models to the relation, **ignoring duplicates**, use `syncWithoutDetaching()`
- set the relation to the exact models, use `sync()`

#### Example:

Calling:

```
$user->articles()->attach(1);
$user->articles()->attach(2);
$user->articles()->attach(1);

echo $user->articles;
```

Will return articles: `1, 2, 1`

Calling:

```
$user->articles()->syncWithoutDetaching([1]);
$user->articles()->syncWithoutDetaching([2]);
$user->articles()->syncWithoutDetaching([1]);

echo $user->articles;
```

Will return articles: `1, 2`

Calling:

```
$user->articles()->sync([1]);
$user->articles()->sync([2, 3]);
$user->articles()->sync([3, 4]);

echo $user->articles;
```

Will return articles: `3, 4`

Answer (score 1):

You also have additional params for sync method:

```
$user->roles()->sync([1,2,3], true);
```

"True" will detach, and false will attach. For example, if you have roles 1,2,3,4 and 5 attached and then you edit and remove 5, sync with "true" will remove 5, while sync with "false" will sync new returned values including 5 already in database.