# Store relationship with pivot table in laravel 4

Tags: laravel-4, relationship, pivot-table

Let me explain what i try to achieve.
lets say i have 20 car types for example sport car or family car etc, and 5 cars for example porsche.

When i create a car i have the option to check multiple car types at the same time that belongs to the car and than save it.

I have done some homework and it looks like using a pivot table is the way to go for this inside laravel.

I have this method inside my cars model:

```
public function types()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('types', 'car_types');
}
```

And this method inside my types model:

```
public function cars()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('Car');
}
```

My tables looks like this:

**cars** 
- id 
- name 
- created_at 
- updated_at

**types** 
- id 
- name 
- created_at 
- updated_at

**car_types** 
- car_id 
- type_id

What im trying to do inside my controller is:

```
    $car = new Car();
    Car::create( Input::except('types') );

    foreach(Input::get('types') as $type)
    {
      $car->types()->associate($type);
      $car->save();
    }
```

This is giving me the following error: 
Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::associate()

I hope someone can help me out with this.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well you are almost there. You're right that the two models, `Car` and `Type` are in a `many to many` relation.

In your models you have code that says:

```
return $this->belongsToMany('types', 'car_types');
```

and

```
return $this->belongsToMany('Car');
```

#### Error #1:

In the `types()` method of the `Car` model as the first parameter you should pass the name of the model, and not the name of the table. So you should change that to something like:

```
return $this->belongsToMany('Type', 'car_types');
```

#### Error #2

In your `Car` model you're defining the pivot table as `car_types`, but the pivot definition is missing from the `Type` model. Either remove `, 'car_types'` from the `types()` method in `Car` model and rename your pivot table to simply `car_type`, or add `, 'car_types'` to your `cars()` method in `Type` model.

#### Error #3

Once all the model stuff is set up correctly, you could do in your controller this:

```
$car = new Car();
$car->name = Input::get('car_name_form_field_name_attribute');
$car->save();

$types = Input::get('types');

$car->types()->sync($types);
```

#### Error #4

I'm not sure if this is just a copy/paste error, but your pivot table seems to be missing a primary key field. Every table needs a primary key field, so your `car_types` table should look something like this:

**car_types**

- id
- car_id
- type_id

You could also use `attach()` instead of `sync()`. More about the difference between these two [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23969879/1396141)

Please try out this code and let us know if it works out.

Comment: Thanks! There was one thing i needed to change and that was making a variable of Car::create( Input::except('types') ); and use that one for attaching the types. thanks alot for helping me out!