# Insert array on multiple rows

Tags: laravel, laravel-4

I have a multiple select:

```
Form::select('color', array('1' => 'Red', '2' => 'Blue', '3' => 'Green', ... ), null, array('multiple'));
```

How can I insert these values into a table on separate rows, like this:

```
  id  |  user_id  |  color
----------------------------
   1  |     1     |    1
   2  |     1     |    2
   3  |     1     |    3
   4  |     1     |    4
   5  |     2     |    1
   6  |     2     |    3
```

In the above example, user with an id of `1` selected 4 different values in the select and each was inserted on a separate row.

I have this working in this way:

```
foreach (Input::get('tags') as $key => $value)
{
    $user_color = new UserColor;
    $user_color->user_id = $user->id;
    $user_color->color = $key;
    $user_color->save();
}
```

Is there a better way of doing this? It seems odd using a foreach loop when it feels like Laravel should have some sort of built-in method of inserting multiple values on multiple rows.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Bulk Insertion in Laravel using eloquent ORM](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12702812/bulk-insertion-in-laravel-using-eloquent-orm)

Comment: The answers there are from 2012. Laravel has changed a lot since then.

Comment: Also, `insert()` does not update `created_at` or `updated_at`.

Comment: Have you tried looping first to create the array itself and then inserting the array after the loop has finished?

Comment: `Input::get('tags')` already is an array. Not sure what you mean.

Comment: If you want to have timestamps updated automatically you have to do it like you do right now.

Comment: You can update your `created_at` and `updated_at` fields in your loop like so: `'created_at' => \Carbon\Carbon::now()->toDateTimeString()`

Comment: never use something like this : foreach (Input::get('tags') as $key => $value)
{
    $user_color = new UserColor;
    $user_color->user_id = $user->id;
    $user_color->color = $key;
    $user_color->save();
}           use case when in your sql instead

Answer (score 1):

As Laravel doc provided,

> You may also use the sync method to attach related models. The sync
>   method accepts an array of IDs to place on the pivot table. After this
>   operation is complete, only the IDs in the array will be on the
>   intermediate table for the model:

In this case,

```
$colors = Input::get('tags');
$user->colors()->sync($colors);
```

Please make sure to set relation in your `User` model :

```
public function colors()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('Color');
}
```

You can also use `attach` method when you parameter is not array. To more clear, [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23968415/laravel-eloquent-attach-vs-sync#23969879) is difference between `attach` and `sync`.