# Laravel tags CRUD

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.3

I have read or watched many laravel tutorials on the web,most of the tutorials' tagging system have a feature:

The tag CRUD has their own router,first,add new tags and select tags when create new post.But if I want to dynamically add tags or update tags when create post like wordpress, How can I do ? (I'm using bootstrap-tagsinput plugin)

For example:

### Tag Router

```
Route::resource('tags','TagsController');
```

> Tags CRUD all work in this way.

**What I want to do is :**

### Post Router

```
Route::resource('posts','PostController');
```

> When I create new post or edit post, I also can add or delete tags without use the Tag Router

For create post I can use laravel's saveMany method like this:

```
    $post = new Post();
    $post->someProperty = $someProperty;
    $post->save();
    $tags = [];
    foreach ($request->tags as $tag) {
        $tags[] = new Tag(['name' => $tag]);
    }
    $post->saveMany($tags);
```

But when I edit a post, I also want to delete tags or add new tags,How can I do for it?

Answer (score 0):

use [this tagging package](https://github.com/rtconner/laravel-tagging) which has all the features you want so you don't have to re-invent the wheel.

So, there you can untag or delete tag or retag completely

```
$post->untag('Cooking'); // remove Cooking tag
$post->untag(); // remove all tags
$post->retag(array('Fruit', 'Fish'));
```

Answer (score 0):

you can easily use:

```
$post->tags()->sync($request->tags, false);
```

you can review the function `sync` [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/eloquent-relationships#updating-many-to-many-relationships) under Syncing Associations section
and you can see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23969879/1290292)

Answer (score 0):

It's too late. But I have same issue and google search for this.
I found a good article here: https://www.amitmerchant.com/attach-detach-sync-laravel/

in my case:

```
public function update(PostEditRequest $request)
    {
        $post = DB::transaction(function() use($request) {
            $post = Post::find($request->id);
            if (!$post) return $this->response404('Post is not found!!!');

            $data = $request->only(['title', 'content']);
            $post->update($data);

            $tags = collect($request->tags); // My tags are [{id: 1, name: 'PHP'}] I got from ajax request
            $post->tags()->sync($tags->pluck('id')); // <- This to add and also remove tag for the post 

            return $post;
        });
        return $this->successResponseWithResource(new PostResource($post));
    }
```

Hope it help someone.