# Laravel 5.4 How to update pivot table?

Tags: laravel, eloquent, pivot-table

I have next structure pivot table: products_equipment_value(id, product_id, equipment_id, value_id).How to update table fields equipment_id and value_id ?

```
 public function equipments()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Equipment', ' product_equipment_value');
    }

    public function values()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Value', ' product_equipment_value', 'product_id', 'value_id')
    }
```

Use(not work)

```
 $product->equipments()->detach();
       foreach($data['eq'] as $key => $val){
         $product->equipments()->attach([
           'equipment_id' =>  $key,
            'value_id' =>$val
          ]);
      }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `withPivot` function on the relations.

```
public function equipments()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Equipment', 'product_equipment_value')->withPivot('value_id');
}
```

Then when you attach the models

```
$product->equipments()
    ->attach([
        $key => ['value_id' =>$val],            
    ]);
```

Comment: And how to deduce Product (simple method)
|product.title|equipment.title|value.title|

Comment: When you call $product->equipments will return a collection of equipments if you want only first one use first() method ($product->equipments->first()->title)

Answer (score 1):

Referring to Many to Many Eloquent's relationship (https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many) you can sync IDs like this :

```
$product->equipments()->sync([array_of_equipments_ids]);
```

Example:

```
$product->equipments()->sync([3, 8, 9, 24]);
```

If you defined the Many to Many inverse relationship you can also do this that way from the equipment instance :

```
$equipment->values()->sync([array_of_values_ids]);
```

If you have extra columns with your pivot table you can add them like this :

```
public function equipments(){
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Equipment', 'product_equipment_value')->withPivot('extra_column1');
}
```

And so :

```
$product->equipments()->sync([1 => ['extra_column1' => 'Value for this column']])
```

Note that you can use sync() or attach() methods to construct many-to-many associations. You can take a look here : https://stackoverflow.com/a/23969879/8620746