# Is there any way to fix Illegal offset type error when i try to update the content of pivot table in laravel

Tags: database, laravel, api, eloquent

I'm trying to update the data of pivot table (i want to change product in the order)

I have :

-product table:

```
id 

 name

product_price

 created_at

 updated_at
```

-order table:

```
id

status

user_id

created_at

updated_at
```

-order_products table:

```
order_id

product_id

product_price

count

created_at

updated_at
```

in Order model:

```
 public function product(){
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Product')->withPivot('count');
}
```

in Prodect model:

```
public function order(){
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Order');
}
```

in controller:

```
public function EditOrder(Request $request , $id){

        $order =  Order::find($id);
    $order->status = $request->status;
    $order->user_id = $request->user_id;
    $order->update();

    $product_ids = $request->products;

    $selectedItems = [];

    foreach ( $product_ids  as $key => $productId) {
        $id1 = $key['product_id'];
        $product = Product ::find($id);
        $count = $key['count'];

        $selectedItems[$productId] = ['product_id' => $id1 ];
        $selectedItems[$productId] = ['count' => $count];
        $selectedItems[$productId] = ['order_id' => $order->id];
        $selectedItems[$productId] = ['price' => $product->product_price];
        $order->product()->updateExistingPivot($selectedItems);
    }
    return  response()->json([
        'message' => 'Success'
    ],200);
```

i faced this error :

```
Illegal offset type in file C:\Users\Acer\Documents\GitHub\easyrest\app\Http\Controllers\ResturantController.php on line 80
```

I want to update product_id and count in order_products

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Laravel 5.4 How to update pivot table?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46274805/laravel-5-4-how-to-update-pivot-table)

Comment: i tried it but it does not work

Comment: Please show us where is line 80 in your code.

Comment: $selectedItems[$productId] = ['product_id' => $id1];

Answer (score 2):

`updateExistingPivot()` expects 2 params, the first being the id of the relationship you want to update, the second being the array of columns you wish to update. You're not passing an `id`, so it's trying to use your array as the `id`, which is why you're getting the error. Fix your logic:

```
foreach($product_ids as $key => $productId) {
    $id1 = $key['product_id'];
    $product = Product::find($id);
    $count = $key['count'];

    $selectedItems[$productId] = ['product_id' => $id1];
    $selectedItems[$productId] = ['count' => $count];
    // $selectedItems[$productId] = ['order_id' => $order->id]; // [1]
    $selectedItems[$productId] = ['price' => $product->product_price];
    $order->product()->updateExistingPivot($productId, $selectedItems[$productId]); // [2]
}
```

[1]: You can omit `order_id`; `$order->product()->updateExistingPivot()` already knows the `order_id` and you're not updating it, so it's redundant.

[2]: You don't want to pass the entire `$selectedItems` array, only the sub-array contained in `$selectedItems[$productId]`

By passing `$productId` as the first argument of `updateExistingPivot()`, Laravel knows what row you want to update, and will use the array keys in `$selectedItems[$productId]` to determine which columns to update to what. I don't know if this will actually update `product_id`, but if it doesn't, you may need to `detach()` then `attach()` the data instead:

```
foreach($product_ids as $key => $productId) {
    $selectedItems[$id1] = ['count' => $count];
    $selectedItems[$id1] = ['price' => $product->product_price];

    $order->products()->detach($productId);
    $order->products()->attach($id1, $selectedItems[$id1]);
}
```