# Difference between `syncPermissions()` and `attachPermissions()`?

Tags: php, laravel

What's the difference between `syncPermissions()` and `attachPermissions()` in Laravel's package Laratrust?

```
$role->attachPermissions($permission);
```

And

```
$role->syncPermissions($permission);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The differences are the same as Laravel's native `attach()` and `sync()` methods for many-to-many relationships.

See: [Laravel Eloquent - Attach vs Sync](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23968415/laravel-eloquent-attach-vs-sync)

Answer (score 0):

> `$admin->attachPermission($createPost);`

```
 // parameter can be a Permission object, array or id 
 // equivalent to $admin->permissions()->attach([$createPost->id]);
```

..

> `$owner->attachPermissions([$createPost, $editUser]);`

```
// parameter can be a Permission object, array or id 
// equivalent to $owner->permissions()->attach([$createPost->id, $editUser->id]);
```

..

> `$owner->syncPermissions([$createPost, $editUser]);`

```
// parameter can be a Permission object, array or id 
// equivalent to $owner->permissions()->sync([$createPost->id, $editUser->id]);
```

From the [Laratrust Docs](https://laratrust.readthedocs.io/en/5.0/).