# Add data to a Laravel pivot table

Tags: laravel

I have a database with 3 tables : `users`, `events` and `user_event`.

I create my event. Once my event is created, I would like to add users.

How can I add him via a form to add users?

My pivot table contain :

`event_id`, `user_id`

Do I need to create a UserEventController?

My model relations :

```
public function users()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('User')->withPivot('user_event');
}
```

For create an event :

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    $this->validate($request, [
        'course_name'  => 'required|max:255',
        'academic_year' => 'required|max:4|min:4',
        'exam_session' => 'required',
        'date_event' => 'required'
    ]);

    $event = new Event();

    $event->course_name  = $request->course_name;
    $event->academic_year = $request->academic_year;
    $event->exam_session = $request->exam_session;
    $event->date_event = $request->date_event;

    $event->save();
}
```

Thanks for your help !

Comment: add your model relations

Comment: @LouisR it's done!

Comment: post your code for adding an event

Comment: I don't add an event, I want to add a user to the already created event. That's why I'm stuck.

Comment: post your code i can't help if you don't ;)

Comment: @LouisR it's done!

Answer (score 0):

So you need to use the `attach()`method :

```
$event->users()->attach($userId);
```

more informations here : [Laravel Eloquent - Attach vs Sync](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23968415/laravel-eloquent-attach-vs-sync)

Answer (score 0):

Since the event is already created, you can just use the event object to add an existing user, create a new one, or maybe even sync a list of users.

```
//create a new user
$event->users()->create(['name' => 'user name', 'email' => 'user email']);

//attach existing user
$event->users()->attach($userId);

//sync multiple existing users passing array of user ids
$event->users()->sync([1,2,4]);
```

You can see details about all of those methods and a few more here: https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/eloquent-relationships#inserting-and-updating-related-models