# why laravel belongsToMany update extra pivot column

Tags: laravel, eloquent-relationship

data:

```
id  modelable_type  modelable_id    category_id slug
7   Modules\Admin\Entities\AdminModel   10  1   admin
8   Modules\Admin\Entities\AdminModel   10  2   admin2
```

and code is :

```
//sync method:
$admin->categoriesRelation()->sync([1 => ['slug' => 'admin'], 2 => ['slug' => 'admin2']]);
```

admin relation:

```
//relation :
public function categoriesRelation(): belongsToMany {
        return $this->belongsToMany(CategoryModel::class, 'category_relations', 'modelable_id', 'category_id')->withPivot('slug')->withPivotValue('modelable_type', static::class);
}
```

queries:

```sql
select * from `category_relations` 
where `modelable_type` = 'Modules\Admin\Entities\AdminModel'
    and `category_relations`.`modelable_id` = 10

update `category_relations` 
set `slug` = 'admin' 
where `modelable_type` = 'Modules\Admin\Entities\AdminModel'
    and `category_relations`.`modelable_id` = 10 and `category_id` in (1)

update `category_relations` 
set `slug` = 'admin2' 
where `modelable_type` = 'Modules\Admin\Entities\AdminModel'
    and `category_relations`.`modelable_id` = 10 and `category_id` in (2)
```

relation  sync  without any data change, All records are updated again.

Comment: Please post your data and queries as text within the question. See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors

Answer (score 0):

The `sync method` will remove any existing records in the pivot table that are not part of update array, and then insert the two records you specified.

If you do not want to update the existing records in the pivot table, you can use the `attach` method instead.

Comment: i use sync method to automatic attach/detach relation.

Comment: Were you successful?

Comment: sync method will not remove exist record in array argument, but why eloquent  update them without any change.

Comment: they are deleted and then recreated w/o any change; of course the IDS will auto increment

Comment: i check eloquent sync method.
Records are not created or deleted simultaneously, but are compared,
New relationships are created and redundant relationships are removed,
But when the data is the same, why are the columns being updated again for no reason?

Comment: see the accepted answer here: might help =>  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23968415/laravel-eloquent-attach-vs-sync

Comment: this relation has extra data in pivot table. And the problem of additional updates is on the same data ( ['slug' => 'admin'] )