# Why can’t I access the BelongsToMany methods on my Eloquent model?

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-10

I have two models, `List` and `Item`, with a many-to-many relationship. Since I don’t care about getting the lists an item is in (just the items in the list), my models only define half the relationship.

```php
class App\Models\List extends Model
{
    protected function items(): Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\BelongsToMany
    { /*...*/ }
}
```

Then I have a route, `Route::post('/list/{item}', [ListController::class, 'item'])` to which a form submits an item and some other data. The controller is responsible for retrieving the correct List model and storing the relationship & details.

```php
class App\Http\Controllers\ListController extends Controller
{
    public function item($request, App\Models\Item $item)
    {
        /* request validation */

        $list = self::current();

        $list->items()->detach($item->id);
        $list->items()->attach($item->id, [/* other data */]);

        $list->save();

        return back();
    }

    static function current(): App\Models\List
    { /*...*/ }
}
```

But whenever I post to the route, I get an error saying the static `items()` method is not defined:

> Call to undefined method App\Models\List::items()

#### Checks

- Dumping the result of `ListController::current()` shows an instance of `App\Models\List`. This instance does have data from the database (where available).
- I have verified that [`BelongsToMany`](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many) is the correct relationship type to return.
- I can return `Item` instances from a `List` instance without accessing the pivot table directly, meaning my table schema matches my model definitions.
- I have verified that the request and route are passing data into the controller as expected.

I started with [`->syncWithoutDetaching()`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72081770/15016042), but it returns the same error. I switched to `->attach()` and `->detach()` for simplicity.

Comment: `protected` methods cannot be used outside the object scope. Means it can only be used inside the object or inside the child class extending the parent class that has protected methods or properties. https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.visibility.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Laravel Eloquent models, methods defining relationships should be declared as public for proper access.

```
public function items()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(Item::class);
}
```